# Recursively Call an Event C#

Tags: c#, events, recursion

I'm looking for a method to call an event recursively. I have the following

```
private void btn_choose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // switch statement to take the user input and decide the outcome.
    switch (Convert.ToInt32(nud_cat_chooser.Value))
    {
        case 1:
            if (Convert.ToInt32(lbl_p1_cat_1_value.Text) == Convert.ToInt32(lbl_p2_cat_1_value.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Stalemate");//message box to inform the user of a statemate.
                playingcards card1 = player1.Dequeue();//creates tempoary instance of the abstract class playign cards to store the cards
                playingcards card2 = player2.Dequeue();//creates tempoary instance of the abstract class playign cards to store the cards
                assign_Values();
                btn_choose_Click();
            }
        ....
    }
}
```

I want to call the btn_choose_click event again to sort out the stalemate. The labels will be given the values from the assign method. But I'm struggling on implementing the call for btn_choose_click(); What arguments must I pass? Can anyone show me an example?

Thanks :)

Comment: btn_choose_Click(sender,e);

Comment: Noooooooooo. Move that lot into another class. Make the first call from the event handler. As far as recursion goes, you need an exit condition, or you run out of stack. It's far from clear what yours is.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson it's tail recursive (at least from this snippet) so there won't be any stack issues.

Comment: @DaxFohl C# doesn't optimize tail recursion, so it will blow the stack rather than going forever, not that going forever is generally preferable.

Comment: Doh, that's right.  Don't know where I left my brain this morning.

Comment: The exit condition for my recursion is the if statement, the method assign values changes the Labels values so if they are no equal the method will not be called again.

Comment: Can I ask a follow up question? The Abstract Data Type variables are created how can I ensure they're there for the next call? I would pass them into the method but they're created because of the stalemate. Any suggestions? Or should I abstract that part and make a separate method?

Comment: @Yop if you use a while loop (see my solution below) instead of recursion then that becomes less of a hassle.  Any particular reason you're leaning toward recursion?

Comment: @DaxFohl not particularly, I don't see much use for recursion in general and prefer iteration but I thought I might aswell give it ago. I'll take a look and see what I can do thanks.

Comment: If there's a simple(ish) iterative solution, always choose it before recursion. Aside from having a finite amount of stack space, they are a major pain to debug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass sender and e.

However, if I were you, I would simply pull the logic out of your handler and put it into a method.  It is a decidedly bad practice to call a handler explicitly.  The event handler is supposed to respond to an event.  If you were to put a break point in your handler, you'd expect it only to be hit while debugging in response to the event in handles, not because some other method elsewhere in your class called it.  E.g.:

```
private void btn_choose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NewMethod();
}
private void NewMethod()
{ 
    switch (Convert.ToInt32(nud_cat_chooser.Value))
    {


        case 1:
            if (Convert.ToInt32(lbl_p1_cat_1_value.Text) == Convert.ToInt32(lbl_p2_cat_1_value.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Stalemate");//message box to inform the user of a statemate.
                playingcards card1 = player1.Dequeue();//creates tempoary instance of the abstract class playign cards to store the cards
                playingcards card2 = player2.Dequeue();//creates tempoary instance of the abstract class playign cards to store the cards
                assign_Values();
                NewMethod();


}
```

Comment: Oh yeah I never through of extracting it into a new method thank you.

Comment: +1 I wish Microsoft never came up with the whole `(sender, e)` thing in the first place.  I've never used `sender` for anything, and I never use the `EventArgs` aspect of `e`.  If `EventHandler` was just `Action<T>` or `Action` instead, situations like this would be avoided.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply call `Button.PerformClick()`. I don't know the name of your button. This will fire your method.

See also [Button.PerformClick()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick.aspx) method at MSDN.

> This method can be called to raise the Click event.

Answer (score 2):

You are going into a land of recursivity, take great care!
Do not call the method directly. This is a bad design. Create a different function, and make it obvious this is a recursive function.

```
private void btn_choose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int action = Convert.ToInt32(nud_cat_chooser.Value);
    this.DequeuePlayer(action); 
}

/// <summary>
/// Recursivly called until there is no more cards
/// </summary>
private void DequeuePlayer(int action)
{
    // switch statement to take the user input and decide the outcome.
    switch (action)
    {
        case 1:
            if (Convert.ToInt32(lbl_p1_cat_1_value.Text) == Convert.ToInt32(lbl_p2_cat_1_value.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Stalemate");//message box to inform the user of a statemate.
                playingcards card1 = player1.Dequeue();//creates tempoary instance of the abstract class playign cards to store the cards
                playingcards card2 = player2.Dequeue();//creates tempoary instance of the abstract class playign cards to store the cards
                assign_Values();
                this.DequeuePlayer(action);
            }
        ....
    }
```

- Extract the data from the UI before calling functions. Separate the layer of your logic
- Do not launch MessageBox.Show in a middle of nowhere
- Test the value of the property Text of you text box. User can put anything in that.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  I have created a separate function now. The message box is just a placeholder at the moment. I'm deciding on what I'm going to do to inform the user and for value of the nud. Its a Numeric Up and Down with a upper and lower limit with int the index of my array :)

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can just call as

```
btn_choose_Click(this, new EventArgs());
```

But be very careful, the sender is to be used to identify which button is calling the event... Now that you are violating it,  you must write proper documentation to mention not to rely on the sender and eventargs parameter inside the event.

Also you can think of write a new method and calling it using a loop... That would be more readable and reliable..

Comment: Okay thank you, I just read this elsewhere online. I don't know what the sender is, Could you explain it?

Comment: @king `EventArgs.Empty` would be better than allocating a new one.

Comment: Sender is the object representation of the Button which initiates that event...  You can access the Button inside the event like... (Button) sender...  It might help when two or three buttons call the same event

Answer (score 1):

I'd do the thing in a while loop.  Making it recursive unnecessarily just makes the code more confusing.

```
private void btn_choose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var continuing= true;
  while (continuing)
  {
    // switch statement to take the user input and decide the outcome.
    switch (Convert.ToInt32(nud_cat_chooser.Value))
    {
        case 1:
            if (Convert.ToInt32(lbl_p1_cat_1_value.Text) == Convert.ToInt32(lbl_p2_cat_1_value.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Stalemate");//message box to inform the user of a statemate.
                playingcards card1 = player1.Dequeue();//creates tempoary instance of the abstract class playign cards to store the cards
                playingcards card2 = player2.Dequeue();//creates tempoary instance of the abstract class playign cards to store the cards
                assign_Values();
            }
        ....
        case end state:
          do something
          continuing= false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
btn_choose_Click(null, null);
```

As long as you are not relying on the sender param in your method. You can even extract a function from your code and invoke it in the onClick event.

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate method from the above code. You can than call them from events and wherever you want.